# struts2-jquery drop down box not populating

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I have a drop down box via the `<sj:select>` tag that I can't seem to get to populate. I have a getter in the action that it is referencing via the `href` but it doesn't seem to trigger that action so it isn't seeing the getter. I'm using this method which should work from what I've seen from a few tutorials but I'm apparently missing something somewhere.

In its current state now it's just rendering and empty drop down box.

Quick rundown of what I think should be happening:

- page should load via `InputAction`, which it does and populates the list variable with a list of 20 strings
- the `<sj:select>` should fire off the action referenced in the href
- that should trigger the `RateClass` action which populates my list box

I am going about it this way because based on the input of this box I will be switching in and out lists of strings for future select boxes in this application.

Action Class:

```
public class RateClass extends InputAction{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -836858635953762820L;
private String selectedUtility;

public String execute(){
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getJSON(){
    System.out.println("YAY JSON!!!");
    return execute();
}

public List<String> getUtilityList() {
    return utilityList;
}

public String getSelectedUtility() {
    return selectedUtility;
}

public void setSelectedUtility(String selectedUtility) {
    this.selectedUtility = selectedUtility;
}
```

}

Struts.XML json package:

```
 <package name="jsonPackage" extends="json-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="rateclass" class="rateclass">
         <result name="success" type="json" />
    </action>
 </package>
```

Bean Definition:

```
    <bean id="rateclass" class="com.action.input.RateClass" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

Relevant .jsp excerpt:

```
    <label for="utility">Utility: </label>
<sj:select style="margin-left:50px;" href="%{remoteurl}" id="utility"
            name="selectedUtility" list="utilityList"
            headerKey="-1" headerValue="Please Select a Utility"/>
```

Struts URL definition:

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" value="rateclass"></s:url>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the prepare() function of my InputAction class that was extended off of my JSON class. Inside of that there was a nullpointer being thrown that wasn't handled due to a DAO object I did not define in my RateClass bean.